# Scroll GridView Automatically to LastRow

Tags: .net, winforms, telerik-grid

Enviroment:

```
   Windows Forms 
   C# 4.0
   RadGridView (Telerik 2010)
```

How do i automaticaly scroll GridView to always view Last Row ?

i want something like :

```
ListBox1.TopIndex = ListBox.Items.count -1;
```

but for GridView

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks i got it , its :

```
  radGridView1.TableElement.ScrollToRow(radGridView1.Rows.Last());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` property.

Answer (score 1):

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dt.Rows.count-1;

or

dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.count-1;

Comment: problem is im using RadGriview which doesnt have this property